# PHP Rest API Call with Authorization

Tags: php, api, rest, authorization

Simple question

Where would I put "Authorization: Bearer cajwune0fnr78ynj2kz6p8bad"

```
$service_url = 'https://example.com/something/something.json';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($curl_response);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($response);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'd put it into:

***old

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Authorization: Bearer cajwune0fnr78ynj2kz6p8bad');
```

***new

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer cajwune0fnr78ynj2kz6p8bad'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Its giving me this error, apparently its not liking the string. Any ideas?

Warning: curl_setopt(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_QUOTE, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES and CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE arguments in /web/com/140330164410217/main.php on line 9